# Most efficient data structure to use for distributions

Tags: data-structures

Use case:

- An element has a value between 0 and Infinity
- A user can make a query like -- "Give me the lowest value that is inside the top 30% of the elements"
- We can store 1000 of the top elements, and at any point more elements can be added.

What data structure could you use to make this work?

---

My thoughts where that a vector could work, but might not be the most efficient for insertion and retrieval.

Tentative idea: Keep the array sorted. If the user asks for the lowest element that meets 30% of the distribution, do array.length * 0.7, and return that element.

---

Comment: There are tradeoffs. For example, array is great on read performance, but terrible in additions and removals. Binary trees are great for modifications at cost of retrieval. B-trees are kind of in between

Comment: hmm this makes me think of an article I read on voxel engine data storage. Apparently the best way is to store the data as a line-feed string and that each run-length is a good representation of an interval tree. "http://0fps.net/2012/01/14/an-analysis-of-minecraft-like-engines/" << about halfway down the article.

Comment: We need more examples of possible queries and size limitations.  Given that example, a sorted array of __every element__, and picking the length * 0.7th element, seems best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely go with a Binary tree, this sorts data very well and allows you to get to what you want relatively quickly.

Arrays are good for insertion or specific indexes, but anytime you are searching for a key, you have a worst-case scenario of O(n), which is not good.

Binary trees have a search algorithm of O(log(n)), which is significantly faster.